# is it possible to get upto three levels of friends list using facebook graph-api

Tags: facebook-graph-api

is it possible to get upto three levels of friends list in facebook by using SDK V2.3?

Please suggest a way if possible.

thanks.

Answer (score 2):

No, this is not possible. Since Graph API v2.0 you even only get those friends which are also using your app.

See

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_0
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.3/user/friends

Comment: Thanks for your answer... is there any alternate solution for same?

Comment: **No**, there is no other solution. And please don't ask for workarounds. It's clearly stated in the docs.